# What is allowed (on a per round) basis for wand use?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, combat

Example: Melee character with two handed weapon and wand on belt.

What is available in a round?
Can this character draw the wand, use it, then stow it in one round?
Effectively using the wand as a ranged attack.

Example: Wizard with two magical staves in a shoulder draw sheath.
Can this character swap staves during each round?

Comment: So there is no difference in the rules between stowing and drawing wands or weapons. Thus, this question already has an answer at the question indicated. If you feel like this does not solve your problem comment here and we'll see if you question can be edited so as not to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it would require your action to switch staves or pull out a wand and sheath it again. You can sheath a weapon or draw a weapon using your free object interaction, but not both. (Addendum: The Dual Wielder feat allows you to draw 2 weapons or sheath 2 weapons using a single object interaction. Note that this does nothing to fix your problem, it just seemed worth mentioning.)

I am currently using [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50526/drawing-and-sheathing-a-weapon-in-5e-and-the-actions-required) as reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "free actions" and "move actions" in 5E. There is a free object interaction as part of another action or as part of movement.

Comment: Sorry. Too much 3.5 edition. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Brain short circuited there. Edited the question again.