# Does the second attack from the Dual Wielder feat require an additional action, or a bonus action, to carry out?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack, actions, two-weapon-fighting

I am looking at taking the Dual Wielder feat (PHB, p. 165), but I am not entirely sure as to how it works specifically. It includes the following benefit, among others:

> You can use two-weapon fighting even when the one-handed melee weapons
> you are wielding aren’t light.

Does this second weapon attack require an additional action, or a bonus action, to carry out?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Two-Weapon Fighting & Bonus Actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49685/two-weapon-fighting-bonus-actions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The second benefit of the [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dual-wielder) feat (PHB, p. 165) refers to the ["Two-Weapon Fighting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) section of the PHB found on page 195:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
> that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
> with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
> hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
> attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon,
> instead of making a melee attack with it.

As such, the second attack requires a bonus action, as described in the Two-Weapon Fighting rule.