# In one round can I Attack, two-weapon Bonus Attack, and Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

I created a lv 6 Ranger in Dnd 5e with the Two Weapon Fighting style. At lv 5 I got Extra Attack as an action. I was wondering if I entered initiate with a dagger in each hand; would I be able to throw a dagger with an action, use a bonus action to throw another dagger in my off hand using TWF, then free action to pull out another dagger, and use my extra attack from taking the attack action to throw that dagger as well?

Comment: related: [Wielding two weapons without “Two-Weapon Fighting” or “Dual Wielder”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69521/wielding-two-weapons-without-two-weapon-fighting-or-dual-wielder)

Comment: My sincerest apologies, I’m slightly a newb to these sites and I’ve never asked a question online before. Lol. But yes it is D&D 5E

Comment: @MrDennler No problem, and thanks for clarifying. I've reopened the question. (Though it looks like it may have an answer already available elsewhere, in which case it will be closed again as a duplicate, but that's not a strike against you in any way.) Our Q&A system can take a bit of getting used to since it doesn't work like many other sites do. If you have questions about how to use our site and its software, you can ask on [meta], and once you reach 20 rep you're also welcome to join us in [chat].

Comment: Note: you can even get around breaking up your action if you do not care about the order of the attacks you described.