# when do I attack i can choose attack with offhand?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, fighter

when do I attack an normal action i can choose attack with offhand?

looks a little weird an fighter dual wielder attack 4 times with one hand and just one with offhand

Comment: Are you asking when you do the bonus action attack for dual wielding or are you understanding that but don't think it makes sense?

Comment: my doubt it's not in the bonus action,but in normal action

Comment: Related on [Does two-weapon fighting give any penalties to the offhand attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140509)