# Do you get a bonus action from dual wielding?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

I have been playing D&D 5e for a while now and I recently made a new Fighter with 2 weapons. I already read many things and the PHB but I can't figure out if I get a bonus action from my first attack so I can make a second attack or if I have to already have a bonus action. If so wouldn't it be really bad on a fighter, at least in the early game? And how do I get this Dual wielding thing so that I get to wield normal weight weapons?

Comment: its not a duplicate i already read that and i couldnt figure out if i realy get the bonus action just by attacking. It just sounded wrong to me.

Comment: It’s a duplicate because it’s the same question. If you aren’t able to solve the issue with the answers there, you may need to ask a question about the *exact* wording you need clarified.

Answer (score 3):

### You do

But you can take only one bonus action, and only on your turn.

See [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat), **Bonus Actions**:

> You can take a bonus action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus action. You otherwise don't have a bonus action to take.
>
> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Attacking with a *Light* weapon explicitly allows you to take such an action.

See [Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/combat#TwoWeaponFighting), **Two-Weapon Fighting**:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand

For more info see [Two-Weapon Fighting & Bonus Actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49685/)

Comment: Isnt it a little op then i mean as far as i did understand you get to basically do 2 attacks in 1 turn starting at lvl 1 with fighter. But i think i played it wrong cuz i added my dex mod to both my hit and dmg roll

Comment: It's not the same as two attacks. The second attack is weaker, since you don't add the damage bonus. Please read the "Two-Weapon Fighting" chapter.

Comment: @AxelLP The second attack's damage lacks your ability modifier (by default), so it deals greatly reduced damage if it hits. You could have a more damaging two-handed weapon instead, or a bigger (non-light) one-handed weapon and a shield. It's not OP, but it's definitely strong in some situations, eg. for rogues who benefit from having more chances to perform their Sneak Attack.

Comment: But the two weapon fighting fighting style that the fighter and ranger has allows me to add the mod to the damage of the second attack but not to my atk dc (d20) right? Didnt write that i got that as my fighting style sorry for that, its my first question on a forum.

Comment: @AxelLP We have a number of Q&A on this site that addresses how the two weapon fighting style looks good from levels 1-4, but once the second attack feature comes at level 5 it does not look anywhere near as good. [Like this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130182/22566) . It's best not to assess features due to their impact on levels 1-4 as that is "introductory adventuring ..."